# Java: println with char array gives gibberish

Tags: java, arrays, char, output

Here's the problem. This code:

```
String a = "0000";
 System.out.println(a);
char[] b = a.toCharArray();
 System.out.println(b);
```

returns

```
0000
0000
```

But this code:

```
String a = "0000";
 System.out.println("String a: " + a);
char[] b = a.toCharArray();
 System.out.println("char[] b: " + b);
```

returns

```
String a: 0000
char[] b: [C@56e5b723
```

What in the world is going on? Seems there should be a simple enough solution, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You could simply do `System.out.println(new String(b));` Using one of String's constructors to convert the char array into a String.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you say

```
System.out.println(b);
```

It results in a call to `print(char[] s)` then `println()`

The JavaDoc for `print(char[] s)` says:

> Print an array of characters. The characters are converted into bytes
>   according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

So it performs a byte-by-byte print out.

When you say

```
System.out.println("char[] b: " + b);
```

It results in a call to `print(String)`, and so what you're actually doing is appending to a `String` an `Object` which invokes `toString()` on the `Object` -- this, as with all `Object` by default, and in the case of an `Array`, prints the value of the reference (the memory address).

You could do:

```
System.out.println("char[] b: " + new String(b));
```

Note that this is "wrong" in the sense that you're not paying any mind to encoding and are using the system default. Learn about encoding sooner rather than later.

Comment: I would start here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - the gist of it is going to be that if you have a bunch of binary data, you really need to know the encoding in order to represent it textually, otherwise you're bound to have abnormalities.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
System.out.println("char[] b: " + Arrays.toString(b));
```

The gibrish you get is the Class name followed by the memory address of the object. Problem occurs when you try to append b with a string `char[] b:` in this case the char array b.toString() method is called thus [C@56e5b723 is printed.

[ indicates that it is an array
C indicates the class in this case char
@56e5b723 indicates the memory location

Comment: No, it's the hashCode() for the object. Here for a char array it just happens to be the internal address, but it's not guaranteed to be this for other objects especially if they override the hashCode() method.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println("char[] b: " + b);
```

This is just like

```
System.out.println(("char[] b: " + b.toString());
```

You can look up "Object.toString()"

Answer (score 4):

An array's `toString()` method (which is what's called when you do `"..." + b`) is only meant to give debugging output. There isn't a special case where a `char[]`'s `toString()` will give you the original string - arrays of all types have the same `toString()` implementation.

If you want to get the original string from the char array, use:

```
String a2 = new String(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use
3:e row!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] txt = input.next().toCharArray();
System.out.println((char[])txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void print(char[] arr) {
    try {
        PrintStream stream
                = new PrintStream(System.out);
        stream.println(arr);
        stream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with this code and how it solves the problem/answers the question of the QP.