# Create a new string that will consist of common letters from other two strings in java

Tags: java

```
public class StringEx {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String s1 ="abcc";
    String s2 = "cbaa";

    getCommon(s1,s2);
}

private static void getCommon(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();

    char[] commonAry = new char[10];

    for(int i=0;i < (c1.length)-1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<(c2.length)-1;j++){

        if(c1[i]==c2[j]){
            int k=0;
            commonAry[k]=c1[i];
            k++; 
        }
    }
    }

    System.out.println(commonAry);

}

}
```

the above program is  giving an output like "c n some square boxer after that".. what is wrong in above code.

Comment: What do you expect `System.out.println(commonAry);` to do? And why?

Comment: length of `commonAry` should be = `min(c1.length, c2.length)`. your teacher will cut marks for `char[10]`

Comment: Once you've answered my question above, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java).

Comment: k never gets past 0, probably consider that too

Comment: put letters of one word in a Set, then iterate over another word and check presence of each letter.

Comment: can you try my answer

Comment: i didn't get the question here?
what OP is expecting?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma `what is wrong in above code.` is the question.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Thanks. I can see that. What is expected was my question.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I was being sarcastic. Either way, how can you not know what he's expecting? `common letters from other two strings` sounds pretty self-explanatory. He's probably expecting `abc`

Answer (score 4):

Use `Set<character>` retainAll() method to get the intersect between the two String

```
public static void getCommon(String s1,String s2){


         char[] s1Array = s1.toCharArray();  
         char [] s2Array = s2.toCharArray();  


     Set<Character>s1CharSet = new HashSet<Character>();  
     Set<Character>s2CharSet = new HashSet<Character>();  

     for(char c:s1Array){  
         s1CharSet.add(c);  
     }  

     for(char c: s2Array){  
         s2CharSet.add(c);  
     }  

     s1CharSet.retainAll(s2CharSet);  

     if(s1CharSet.size()==0){  
        System.out.println("There are no common characters between the two strings");  
     }  

     else{  
         System.out.println(s1CharSet);  
     }  


     }
```

**output**

```
  [b, c, a]
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/XKg6Tq)</kbd>

Comment: Did you actually run this, and get `"abc"` as the output?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes I get the abc as the output and add the Demo link check it out

Comment: OK.  You do realise that with different input strings, this isn't going to work out quite as nicely, right?  There are at least three bugs, which coincidentally fail to manifest, with this particular input.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks, i have found the difficults when I tried by using == comparator ,so i tried it retainAll method in set, can you plz check my edited answer..

Comment: It looks much, much better now; and as far as I can see, it works correctly.  Note that you don't need to iterate through the `char` arrays yourself, to make the sets.  You can just write `Set<Character> s1CharSet = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(s1Array));`

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you are not looping over all the char array, your looping
    should be:

```
for(int i=0;i < (c1.length);i++)
```

secondly, you must initialize the index k out of your loops, 
    thirdly, this operation is not commutative, that means

```
getCommon(String s1, String s2)
```

and

```
getCommon(String s2, String s1)
```

won't give the same results,

and finally, because you're trying to get common letters, so why not
        break the inner loop just after finding any similar character in the
        other array?

- Note: you should omit any redundancy in your first string, or in the 
  result, after calculation.
- and for square letters, I refer you to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505323/1951298