# Alphanumeric otp generator returning same values every time

Tags: java, random, secure-random

I have been trying to write a simple java program to display random alphanumeric numbers every time. However I am getting the same result as **[C@a3a380**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;

public class NumericOTPGenerator 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int length=5;
        System.out.println("OTP : "+generateOTP(length));
    }
    static char[] generateOTP(int length)
    {
        String capitalChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String smallChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String symbols = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/.?<>)";
        String values = capitalChars + smallChars + numbers + symbols;
        char[] generatedOTP = new char[length];
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            generatedOTP[i] = values.charAt(rand.nextInt(values.length()));

        }
        return generatedOTP;
    }
}
```

Please suggest how do I resolve this issue.

Comment: `return Arrays.toString(generatedOTP);` instead

Comment: I don't think so your program is fine, It's returning new OTP every time. May be your are making `toString()` somewhere in your program

Comment: Arrays,toString() has solved the issue. These urls have helped to understand.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505274/java-println-with-char-array-gives-gibberish

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: It is not smart to create PRNG object every time when you call the function. First of all its slows the program and the numbers are not so secure random.

Comment: I have modified the code accordingly. Also instead of toString, I have used String generatedOTPString = new String(generatedOTP) so that I get the output in the desired manner (not in array format).